How can I deny all URLs that end with .php?
I have the following .htaccess lines that only allows to visit index.php and disallows access to install.php, update.php and all other PHP files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</IfModule>

I need something like this because I have a watchdog full of page not found clutter like adminer.php, pma/index.php, /wp-login.php, /phpmyadmin/index.php, and endless other variations.
This code seems to work fine. For URLs ending with .php, it returns an Apache Forbidden page instead of the whole website. There are no records of page not found in the watchdog. Which is exactly what I need.
Is it a good idea to place this code in the .htaccess file on Drupal 10 websites? Are there any better ways to solve this problem?
